# Can one wave down the inter-town minibuses in Thailand?

Tags: buses, thailand

I need to get to [Chonbury](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/2+Thanon+Long+Had+Bangsaen,+Tambon+Saen+Suk,+Amphoe+Mueang+Chon+Buri,+Chang+Wat+Chon+Buri+20130,+Thailand/@13.2846908,100.9145756,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x30e281a535074ae9:0xa6239d6a45d0f8a5!2sSoi+B+2,+Tambon+Bang+Phun,+Amphoe+Mueang+Pathum+Thani,+Chang+Wat+Pathum+Thani+12000,+Thailand!3b1!8m2!3d13.9936302!4d100.5858369!3m4!1s0x3102b4c1d8a922b3:0xcb3b38f860dc79fc!8m2!3d13.2846856!4d100.9167643). At the moment I am in [Bang Na](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Regent+Home+7/@13.6662618,100.6093558,15.63z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x30e281a535074ae9:0xa6239d6a45d0f8a5!2sSoi+B+2,+Tambon+Bang+Phun,+Amphoe+Mueang+Pathum+Thani,+Chang+Wat+Pathum+Thani+12000,+Thailand!3b1!8m2!3d13.9936302!4d100.5858369!3m4!1s0x0:0xcafc81e0e9dbdfe9!8m2!3d13.6757511!4d100.6040838). I have checked and a major road ([Sukhumvit Road](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/13.6752833,100.6032931/The+North+Park+Condominium/@13.5089598,100.6853144,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m9!4m8!1m1!4e1!1m5!1m1!1s0x0:0x6017e35773487625!2m2!1d100.9209312!2d13.2838917)) to get to Chonbury is next door.

Minibuses go from three locations [Victory Monument, Central Plaza Rama II, and Major Rungsit](http://www.pattayaconcierge.com/chonburi/transportation-to-chonburi.php).

[image]

I was wondering instead of getting there could I just wave the minibus down when it's going past?

**Can one wave down the inter-town minibuses in Thailand?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vans are not real keen to waste time stopping to find out where you are going, especially in a big city like Bangkok. Once they leave their start point they are in a rush to get the trip done, so as to make another round.  Much more money in making a another trip, than adding one passenger.

And since many are labeled in Thai, driven by folks who don't speak much English, how would you know which to flag and how to negotiate?

Far better to go to the embarkation point, get on the correct van and enjoy the adrenaline pumping thrill ride in its entirety.

Comment: Hi Tom, indeed there are no English writings and they only leave when completely full - which means no empty seats to fill to begin with.... Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Thai government policy re intercity minivans is in flux due to safety concerns.  Twenty-five people died in one van accident over the New Year holidays.  Part of the policy change is that they are trying to move the points of departure from Victory Monument and other hubs to the regular intercity bus stations.  Here’s a [news report](http://bangkok.coconuts.co/2016/10/26/passenger-vans-move-victory-monument-and-chatuchak-life-gets-harder-bangkoks-poor) from October 2016:

> The more than 4,000 vans have been moved yesterday from the easily accessible neighborhoods of Victory Monument and Chatuchak to the city's harder to access bus terminals.
>
> All of the inter-province vans will now leave from: Mo Chit 2, for vans headed North, Northeast and central; Sai Tai Mai, for vans headed South; and Ekkamai, for vans headed East, reported Bangkok Post.
>
> That means if you want to take a trip to Pattaya, you have to catch the van at Ekkamai. For a ride to Hua Hin beach in Prachuap Kirikhan province, take the van at Sai Tai Mai.

In your case, Ekkamai is on the Skytrain line and in the same neck of the woods as Bang Na.  It should be easy to get there.  If you choose not to go there, I’m not sure if you can wave down the vans.  Actually, the second class coach-type buses from Ekkamai to Chonburi do stop to pick up passengers along the way (which really slows things down.) You might succeed in waving those down if you want to try.